# Executing chrome driver without sufficient privileges

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dll, selenium-chromedriver

I was hoping for maybe some suggestions on how to get selenium working in following case.  I am trying to implement smooth update of chromedriver with limited permissions on environment.

The problem occurs when Google Chrome is upgraded by third party to a newer version and the chromedriver stays the old version. The real problem is because the new version of application requires a new build, new documentation ... etc.
During development I run VS as admin, so no problem when downloading chromedriver.exe. Also normal user can execute it since it is already downloaded.

I tried different ways:

1. Embed driver into dll, extract it when needed, delete it when not needed any more. The problem is I don't have sufficient permissions to extract or create. I need admin privileges but I don't have it.
2. Load driver from local/remote location. Here is the problem that the program (chromedriver.exe) is blocked by a group policy.
3. Loading driver using DriverManager. Since VS is run as Admin, chrome driver detects version and download it beside application. It stop working when applicaiton is not runned as Admin. I tried to download it into users Downloads folder but it is blocked by a group policy.
4. There is another idea which I am not sure if it is possible. Emmbed chromedriver.exe as Resource in dll and call it. Here is the problem that I need a path for Constructor (ChromeDriver), but I don't have it since it is packed in dll. The idea is when browser is upgraded, new dll is built with new chrome driver and added as dll beside "first" application.

The question is: is it possible to implement the 4th idea or do you maybe have another idea/example?

Comment: Can you download the file into a different folder on the user's computer? Can you download these files to `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP")`? That usually goes to `%APPDATA%\Local\Temp`. See [TEMP vs TMP in Environment Variables](https://superuser.com/q/709953/389858).

Comment: The problem was solved with 3rd approach using DriverManager. User runs application as normal user. If new version is needed, the user gets information, that new driver needs to be downloaded with admin privileges. When admin runs application, driver downloads automatically and it is available for user and admin.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question. Future readers might find it useful.